# Create vertical timeline using R packages timevis and shiny

Tags: r, shiny, timeline

I have two questions with regard to creating a vertical timeline in R, using timevis and shiny. Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks in advance for the reply! (btw I am still a novice in R)

1: All timelines coded with timevis I see are horizontal (Y = 0). Is it possible to change the orientation to a vertical timeline?

2: Is it possible to have text with position '-1' to the lefthand side of the timeline, and text with position '1' on the righthand side of the timeline?

The code, adopted from cran website is as follows:

```
data <- data.frame(
  id      = 1:4,
  content = c("Item one", "Item two",
              "Ranged item", "Item four"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11",
              "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14"),
  position = c(-1, 1, -1, 1)
  )


library(shiny)
library(timevis)
        
if (interactive()) {

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    timevisOutput("timeline"),
      ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$timeline <- renderTimevis(
      timevis(data.frame(start = data$start, content = data$content))
    )
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      setItems("timeline",
               data.frame(start = data$start))
    })
  }
)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604527/vertical-vistime-timeline-and-overlapping-geom-text-labels

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. `timevis` is based on the javascript library `vis.js` version 4.16.1, and this library does not have a vertical option.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! Then I will continue with package ggplot (now also only horizontal). But if I don't succeed I will post my question in a new thread

Comment: @EvaA glad I could help. If the answer was helpful, please consider to accept it. And sure, if you have more questions ask a new one.

Comment: I tried, but I am new to Stack overflow and have only 1 (out of 15) reputations. It was helpfull, so when I have enough I will upvote your answer