# Vertical vistime timeline and overlapping geom_text labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, vistime

I'm trying to draw a vertical timeline using [`vistime`](https://github.com/shosaco/vistime/blob/372da36791cbdb7ad7d6841ed991e55b36f77e06/R/plot_ggplot.R) with its `ggplot` plotting option. My main intention is to better integrate it with text, side by side. This is the code:

```
library("vistime")
library("plotly")
data <- read.csv("../../data/programming.csv")
g <- gg_vistime(data, col.event="Item", col.start="Start.Date", col.end="End.Date", col.group="Group")
g + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, color='blue4',size=14) )+coord_flip()
```

[image: Image result]

As you can see, as I'm doing the `coord_flip`, the labels intersect with each other. I'd like to make the labels go vertical. This is code that draws them:

https://github.com/shosaco/vistime/blob/372da36791cbdb7ad7d6841ed991e55b36f77e06/R/plot_ggplot.R#L83-L91

So that means that it's a `geom_text` sentence. Is there some way to change the orientation of geom_text-drawn text *once it's done*? Can I use some `theme` command to do that? Barring that, is there any way I can change the placement of the labels using `vistime`?

Comment: Why do you keep `element_text(angle=90)`?

Comment: @Waldi that's for the x axis labels

Comment: thanks, I read too fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deconstruct any [`ggplot2`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) visualization with (surprisingly) [`ggplot_build`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot_build.html) (actually, what it does is to create elements that can be rendered using the plain vanilla `plot`).

```
data <- read.csv("data/programming.csv")


g <- gg_vistime(data, col.event="Item", col.start="Start.Date", col.end="End.Date", col.group="Group") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, color='blue4',size=14) )+coord_flip()

g.d <- ggplot_build(g)

g.d$data[[4]]$angle <- 90

rebuilt <- ggplot_gtable(g.d)

png(filename="img/timeline.png", width=240, height=960)
plot(rebuilt)
dev.off()
```

That creates a data frame with different elements of the plot, including `g.d$data` which contains, effectively, the data and its properties when rendered in its 4th element. `g.d$data[[4]]$angle` contains the angle of all the `geom_text` elements that have been rendered. So once you get that, it's just a matter of changing it individually or colectively to what you want. You need to reconstruct the plot using [`ggplot_gtable`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot_gtable.html?q=ggplot%20_%20tatable) and then use the core `plot` command to plot and render it any way you want, in this case a `png`.

At any rate, `ggplot_build` allows you to introspect the data structures and different pieces of the graph created using ggplot, changing any one of its layers, metadata or pieces *after* they have been created. In our case, it produces [the intended effect](https://github.com/JJ/cv/blob/master/img/timeline.png)